# GIF stops working when AJAX call is running

Tags: jquery, ajax, gif

I am reading a large text file using AJAX and jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "testing.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (returnText) {
        $("#viewDescription").text(returnText);
    }
});
```

Then, I thought of showing a [popup](http://demo.webstutorial.com/loading/) with an [animated GIF](http://demo.webstutorial.com/loading/loading.gif) while the request finishes. I did this using the following code:

```
$("#popup").on("ajaxSend", function () {
    $(this).show();
}).on("ajaxStop", function () {
    $(this).hide();
}).on("ajaxError", function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

---

```
<div style="display: none;" id="popup">
    <img src="loading.gif" />
</div>
```

The popup is shown and hidden correctly, but the problem is that the GIF stops while jQuery AJAX call is running. It doesn't work in any of the browsers. What can be the problem please?

Comment: Just so you know, `.bind()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7.+.

Comment: @MBJ What should I use instead?

Comment: just replace bind with `.on()`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#mybtn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#popup").show(); // Show the loader
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "testing.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(returnText) {
            $("#popup").hide(); // Hide on success
            $("#viewDescription").text(returnText);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#popup").hide(); // Hide on error
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
$('#mybtn').on('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "testing.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        beforeSend:function(){
             $("#popup").show(); // Show the loader
        },
        success: function(returnText) {
            $("#popup").hide(); // Hide on success
            $("#viewDescription").text(returnText);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#popup").hide(); // Hide on error
        }
    });
});
```